# Problems with snackbar in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to use the snack-bar from angular materials, but I encountered a problem - the snack bar doesn't appear at the button of the screen, it appears under the button that calls for it. Another thing that happens that it also puts the text from the snack bar on my page.[image]

Here's the code I used:

Snackbar.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MdSnackBar} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-snack-bar',
  templateUrl: './snack-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snack-bar.component.css']
})
export class SnackBarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public snackBar: MdSnackBar) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openSnackBar() {
    this.snackBar.open("Hello World","action",{duration: 500});
  }
}
```

Snackbar.html

```
<button md-button (click)="openSnackBar()" aria-label="Show an example snack-bar">
  Click me
</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SnackBarComponent } from './components/snack-bar/snack-bar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you: imported the SnackBarModule? configurated a material theme? Did you meant snack-bard.component.html instead of Snackbar.html? Do you use any other css libraries/files?

Comment: yes, I imported the MdSnackBarModule in the app.module.ts. I didn't configured any material theme because because the documentation didn't say anything about it, I followed exactly what was on the official material page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import one of the prebuilt themes in your project. I tried without the prebuilt theme and snackbar was causing the problem you mentioned.

[Plunker without prebuilt theme](https://plnkr.co/edit/RgXCVDpNWyrKmshFAOsM?p=preview)

Once I added it, snackbar in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/z5ky5iAUClpUUikgz7WX?p=preview) worked fine.

Run a test by adding following in your index.html `head`

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add to your css:

```
body {
     height:100%;
}
```